# Why do (some) answers get more votes than their questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've seen it throughout SE networks that sometimes the answer to a given question gets much more votes than the question itself (Examples [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110502/how-to-use-public-transport-in-russia-with-limited-russian-knowledge), [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/are-there-any-instances-where-short-run-demand-supply-is-more-elastic-than-long) and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49735/is-it-safe-to-wear-a-helmet-without-a-plastic-covering)).

Is there any reason in particular why this is so? If the answer is useful, why isn't the question that prompted it?

**Note:** I'm not necessarily speaking about those examples in specific, but the general trend of Q&A on the SE networks

Comment: Probably because _answers_ are generally received as more useful than _questions_.

Comment: Why *should* questions be getting more votes than they're getting now?

Comment: I don't know that they do really. For every example you give, you could find 10 more where the question has more votes. It takes a great answer to get votes like that and not all answers are good or even right.

Comment: I understand the question but, like the answer says, who knows why anyone does anything. A couple of things I can offer, people coime looking for answers, not questions. You can find your answer on a question that does not reflect your issue anmd there for only vote on the answer that worked.

Comment: Why are pearls considered more valuable than sand that caused their creation? https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: Well, at least now you have another example.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any reason in particular why this is so?

We can only speculate about the average visitor's behavior, but as mentioned in my comment, answers are what is received to be helpful for them over time, and they'll tend to upvote it for that reason.

Why they don't upvote the question as well along is left in the dark.

<sub>I've noticed that's going to change a bit for self-answered questions, where I often get upvotes for both, the question and the answer.</sub>